# Pretty-print C++ STL containers

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading, pretty-print

I would like to have a single template that once and for all takes care of pretty-printing all STL containers via `operator<<`. In pseudo code, I'm looking for something like this:

```
template<container C, class T, String delim = ", ", String open = "[", String close = "]">
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & o, const C<T> & x)
{
    o << open;
    // for (typename C::const_iterator i = x.begin(); i != x.end(); i++) /* Old-school */
    for (auto i = x.begin(); i != x.end(); i++)
    {
        if (i != x.begin()) o << delim;
        o << *i;
    }
    o << close;
    return o;
}
```

Now I've seen plenty of template magic here on SO that I never thought possible, so I'm wondering if anyone can suggest something that would match all containers `C<T>`. Maybe something trait-ish that can figure out if something has the necessary iterator?