# Can range-based for loops be aware of the end?

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

Given the minimal C++11 STL example:

```
set<int> S = {1,2,3,4};
for(auto &x: S) {    
   cout << x;
   cout << ",";
}
```

Is there a way to check if `x` is the one right before the end? The goal in this example is to output `1,2,3,4` and not the final comma at the end. Currently I use a standard for loop with two iterators,

```
set<int>::const_iterator itr;
set<int>::const_iterator penultimate_end_itr = --S.end();
for(itr=S.begin(); itr!=penultimate_end_itr;++itr) 
    cout << (*itr) << ',';
cout << (*penultimate_end_itr);
```

Which works, but is terribly cumbersome. Is there a way to do the check within the range-based for loop?

**EDIT:** The point of the question is *not* to print out a comma separated list. I want to know if a range-based for loop has any knowledge of the penultimate element in the list (i.e. is it one before the end). The minimal example was presented so we all have a common code block to talk about.

Comment: There is no elegant way to solve this problem. Hide the ugly in a function and move on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430757/c-array-to-string

Comment: @Shmiddty not quite, I'm using the sample example as input but my question is about accessing range-based for loops, and their awareness to the end of the container.

Comment: This *specific* problem has been solved much more cleanly using [infix_ostream_iterator](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13176/infix-iterator-code). `copy(begin(S), end(S), infix_ostream_iterator<int>(cout, ","));`. As far as the core question goes, however, I believe the correct answer is short and simple: "no."

Comment: You can't portably call `--` on an rvalue.  Use `std::prev`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The very purpose of range-based for loops is to forget the iterator. As such, they only allow you access to the current value and not the iterator. Would the following code do it for you?

```
set<int> S = {1,2,3,4};

std::string output;
for(auto &x: S) {    
   if (!output.empty())
       output += ",";
    output += to_string(x);
  }

cout << output;
```

**EDIT**

Another solution: Instead of comparing iterators (as one would do with "normal" for loops), you could compare the addresses of the values:

```
set<int> S = {1,2,3,4};
auto &last = *(--S.end());
for (auto &x : S)
{
    cout << x;
    if (&x != &last)
        cout << ",";
}
```

Comment: @ViralShah Please stop attempting to introduce random bolding of words in your edits. That isn't helping anybody, it just makes the post ugly.

Comment: Note that `str()` returns *a copy* of the stored string, which makes the above code extremely inefficient (worst case quadratic). Better to use a bool flag to indicate the same condition.

Comment: @Hooked How about using addresses of the values given by the range-based for loop, instead of comparing iterators? See my edit.

Comment: Note that you could do `&(*S.rbegin())` as a simpler way to get the last element.

Comment: `if (output.size())`: Really nice trick ! However I would replace it by `if(!output.empty())` to avoid size computation for each iteration.

Answer (score 7):

[Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/iterator_range.html) can help out here:

```
if (std::begin(S) != std::end(S)) {
    std::cout << *std::begin(S);
    for (const auto &x: boost::make_iterator_range(std::next(std::begin(S)), std::end(S))) {
        std::cout << ", " << x;
    }
}
```

A much more flexible approach is to index the range, using [`boost::adaptors::indexed`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/indexed.html) (since Boost 1.56):

```
for (const auto &element: boost::adaptors::index(S)) {
    std::cout << (element.index() ? ", " : "") << element.value();
}
```

In versions of Boost prior to 1.56 `boost::adaptors::indexed` won't work but you can easily write a work-alike:

```
template <typename... T>
auto zip(const T&... ranges) -> boost::iterator_range<boost::zip_iterator<decltype(boost::make_tuple(std::begin(ranges)...))>>
{
    auto zip_begin = boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(std::begin(ranges)...));
    auto zip_end = boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(std::end(ranges)...));
    return boost::make_iterator_range(zip_begin, zip_end);
}

template<typename T>
auto enumerate(const T &range) -> boost::iterator_range<boost::zip_iterator<boost::tuple<
    boost::counting_iterator<decltype(boost::distance(range))>, decltype(std::begin(range))>>>
{
    return zip(boost::make_iterator_range(boost::make_counting_iterator(0),
        boost::make_counting_iterator(boost::distance(range))), range);
}

for (const auto &tup: enumerate(S)) {
    std::cout << (tup.get<0>() ? ", " : "") << tup.get<1>();
}
```

This is using the `zip` function from [Sequence-zip function for c++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511035/sequence-zip-function-for-c11)

Comment: Thanks for the boost approach, I always appreciate seeing these types of (albeit complicated) solutions - I learn so much. Can't beat the tie in with one of my previous questions!

Comment: There is arguably no need for a hand-rolled solution; Boost.Range provides the [indexed](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/indexed.html) range adaptors for the exact purposes of the OP.

Comment: @LucDanton unfortunately `indexed` doesn't work with range for loops; the index is a method on the iterator rather than being available through indirection.

Comment: @ecatmur and anybody else from Google, while this was the case it isn't true anymore, as you can see there is a for-range-indexed example in the 1.56 docs: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/indexed.html

Comment: @SamKellett wow, that's a pretty bold (breaking API) change! I'll add an example for Boost.Range 1.56.