# What is the scope of returned values from boost::algorithm::join?

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost

In what ways can you use the return values from things like boost::algorithm::join?

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss<<"quack";
std::cout << ss.str().c_str() << std::endl; // bad idea
```

This is a bad idea, explained in sbi's comment in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1430774/

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
v.push_back("foo");
v.push_back("bar");
std::cout << boost::algorithm::join(v,"-").c_str() << std::endl; // what about this?
```

That made me wonder if this has the same problem?

Could someone give an explanation of the scope of such return values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are not storing the reference to the char* there is no problem with both expressions:

From the standard.. http://isocpp.org/std/the-standard

```
Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the 
full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they
were created. [12.2/3]
```

So in both cases above you use the char* pointer in the expression. The boost::algorithm::join and stringstream.str() are available till the end of the expression and so is the c_str pointer.

sbi comment in the link you sent referred to taking c_str() from a temporary string in one expression storing it in a const char* and passing that to a C function in a second statement.

Also I usually try use c_str only when calling C style functions or external library functions that require const char*.
In the case of an ostream<< it already accepts std::string and it takes 2 sec's to add operator<< functions to support new types.