# What does star sign(*) in `std::string(*)(int)`

Tags: c++, boost

Here is code, I don't understand star sign(*) in `std::string(*)`

```
using boost::algorithm::join;
using boost::adaptors::transformed;
auto tostr = static_cast<std::string(*)(int)>(std::to_string);
```

Here is [original code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430757/c-vector-to-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a pointer to function accepting `int` parameter and returning `std::string` - exactly what `std::to_string` does.

As @PeteBecker pointed out, the cast there is needed because there are actuall multiple overloads for `to_string`, accepting different arguments (ints, doubles, shorts, etc). The cast allows the compiler to pick one of them.

Comment: @PeteBecker, good point, btw. Would you mind if I incorporate it into my answer?